# Graphs: probability of two vertices, chosen at random, of being connected by a link

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

If I choose the vertices *h* and *k* in a simple graph uniformly, I know the probability of them being joined by an edge is
$
\frac{2e}{n(n-1)}
$
, where:

- *e* is the number of edges in the graph,
- *n* is the number of vertices,
- *n(n-1)/2* is the total number of possible links.

This is not true, in general, when the vertices are chosen randomly but not uniformly.

The question is, does the formula hold true if I choose *h, k* in a manner that is not directly influenced by their degree or neighbors, but still not uniformly?

---

Answered below: It really does depend on how I choose the vertices.

Comment: I have two questions: (1) Is this a simple graph?  (2) By connected do you mean joined by a path, or by an edge?

Comment: @paw88789: (1) Yes. (2) Joined by an edge. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "directly influenced by". For instance, I could take the distribution that always picks a particular vertex p and then a particular vertex q. This doesn't seem to directly reference either their neighbors or degrees. The probability that the two vertices I pick "randomly" are connected by an edge is either 0 or 1 depending of whether or not p and q are actually adjacent.